# Python BeautifulSoup: How to return the html tag that the html text comes from?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am hoping to iterate through a list of urls to find specific information about various stocks. However, I need to find the html tag where specific text came from. For example, take text on this [AMZN stock ticker](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN?p=AMZN):
The text shows "Market Cap". I want to find where this comes from and return it. By inspecting element, I find the html tag says: **Market Cap**. I am hoping to have it return the previously bolded text and the tag above it: **Market Cap**

I tried to do something the like following:

parent_tag = soup.find(text="Market Cap")
print(parent_tag)

It just returned "Market Cap".

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, could you clarify what you're trying to receive as the output?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find parents, you can try BS4's `find_parent` and `find_parents` which are both very straightforward. See [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) for those two methods, and their example:

```py
a_string = soup.find(string="Lacie")
a_string
# 'Lacie'

a_string.find_parents("a")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>]

a_string.find_parent("p")
# <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
#  and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

a_string.find_parents("p", class_="title")
# []
```